# Responsive Image Problems

Tags: html, css, image, aspect-ratio

These are the constraints:  The image must always maintain its original aspect ratio.  If the parent container's width is too small, then resize the image to fit within it.  The maximum height of the image is 400 pixels.  The maximum width of the image is the width of the parent container.  The problem:  The images does not maintain its aspect ratio when restricted by the parent's width.  Here is the CSS I have:

```
img.myImage {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:400px;
}
```

**EDIT:** To add to the difficulty, this is the parent component:

```
div.programContainer {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**EDIT:  Solution:**
Sorry, this had nothing to do with the image itself, removing the unnecessary flex-box in the parent container solved the problem.

Comment: I'm using width:100% all the time. Have you tried this?

Comment: 100% width stretches the image horizontally and messes up the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css like this:

```css
.img-responsive{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://minisoft.com.bd/uploads/ourteam/rafiq.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Rafique">
```

Answer (score 0):

As @EdangJeorlie says, you'd need `width: 100%` to resize the image when the browser is resized. An example is [here](http://jsbin.com/sibozufava) on JSBin.

Just as a heads-up, I believe you could get rid of `height: auto` as that would be the default. Hope this helps!

Comment: I need to do this without specifying the max width in pixels.  The width of the original image may vary from image to image.  The width needs to be automatically calculated.

Comment: @DanielWilliams: Am I correct in thinking you sorted it now?

Comment: yes, I have fixed my own problem.  My original code for the image was correct.

Comment: Awesome @DanielWilliams. Just wanted to check it's sorted -- glad it worked for you. All the best!